# Importing .eml files into Exchange Discovery Folder

Tags: exchange-2010, discovery

I am needing to import over 18mm eml files into Exchange (this is for a client, so I'm restricted on what I can do - flexibility). They do not want these emails to go to the actual users email, so they do not want them to show up in the users inbox, deleted ..etc. They want to be able to search for these emails for litigation purposes ... hence the discovery folder.

I have looked into the Pickup folder, which does not do what I want. I have also been writing some C# code to use the EWS (Exchange Web Service) Managed API, but so far I have not found anything to work for me. The EWS Managed API does not have any methods available to do what I am needing either. I have also looked at the EWS (not the Managed API) as it has an UploadItem(s) call, this does not seem feasible due to the Data property which is an encoded [Fast Stream](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Exchange-Fast-Transfer).

Keeping the original email dates is important, some of solutions I have found (such as the EWS Managed API CreateItem method) changes the dates of the emails.

The Exchange server is 2010 SP1.

I have looked through other questions/answers and they do not really match up with what I'm needing to accomplish. These are older emails that have already been removed from the users mailbox. So to turn around and put these emails into the Users inbox would (of course) be very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Urmm.. maybe not the easiest nor the quickest way or maybe i got the wrong end of the tail... why not public folders with relevant security applied and import the EML files?

Outlook can open EML with a bit of reg-hack (http://www.msoutlook.info/question/354)

There are paid solutions to convert EML files to MSG or bulk into PST and then simply move them over to public folders? One example: http://www.aid4mail.com/import-export-mail.php?

(assumption that user is/will be using MSFT Outlook)

Comment: "why not public folders with relevant security applied and import the EML files" - Sorry, I'm not following you. How do you import eml files into a public folder?

Comment: You would create a public folder mailbox, create several folders (if required) for various categories/areas. Rather then application hack to open EML files, i would use one of the paid solution to convert the bulk EML messages to PST, i would then open this PST and copy the content to relevant folders within the public mailbox. I would then apply security to these folders to those who should or shouldn't be able to access these. Is that any clearer?